# Charging my Droid with USB using Mac

Tags: usb, macbook, android, charging

I only have the USB connect for my phone, so I've been plugging it into my macbook to charge it. But when the phone is completely dead it won't charge whatsoever and the bootloader screen comes up. Is there any way that I can get passed this so my phone will actually charge?

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10536/device-cannot-be-charged-via-usb

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [USB charger](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/usb-universal-600ma-charger-37).

Basically, you plug your USB into this and plug it into the wall. That way, you don't have to use the computer either. Its only $3.41 (includes free shipping.) If you are not in North America, the website has these for other countries too.